# How to get the element which triggered the event via backbone event handler

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a view.

```
//define View
var CreatePollView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #addOption": "addOption",
        "change .dynamicInput": "changeInputs"
    },
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "render", "addOption", "changeInputs");
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },
    changeInputs: function () {
        var newVal = $(this).val(); // this throws exception in jquery script
        this.model.set("Subject", { Subject: newVal });
    }, ....
```

How can I access the element (it is an input element) on which the change event was triggered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting an exception because you are calling `_.bindAll` on `changeInputs`.  When you do that, you are saying that `changeInputs` will be bound to your object's context whenever it gets called.

In other words, when you refer to `$(this)` you are sending an instance of `CreatePollView` into jQuery, which it doesn't like.

You want to keep this binding, though, because you are accessing your model (`this.model`) so `this` needs to be the instance of `CreatePollView`.

Instead, you can get an event from your function and use the `target` or some other piece of information:

```
changeInputs: function(e) { }
```

Comment: +1 for the added explanation on _.bindAll really interesting i sometimes still struggle with these binds :)

Comment: inside of your `changeInputs` method, you can get the specific element that was changed by calling `$(e.currentTarget)` or `$(e.target)` like Brian suggested, depending on your needs. `e` is a jquery event args object, so read up on jquery's documentation to understand the diff.

Comment: thanks guys @Sander. Good explanation. It seems like a proper way to do it.  In the meanwhile I managed to get it working, but I do not really understand where does the arguments collection come from....see the code below

changeInputs: function () {
            var newVal = arguments[0].srcElement.value;
            this.model.set("Subject", { Subject: newVal });
        },

Comment: @Tom: `arguments` is an array of the arguments that got passed in, regardless of what you define in your function def.  So, `function(e) { e.srcElement }` is the same as `function() { arguments[0].srcElement }`.  Obviously, you should prefer the former in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
changeInputs: function(e){
   //use e.target
   ...
}
```